# How to create emulator for ONEPLUS TWO?

Tags: android, android-emulator, oneplusone, oneplustwo, oneplusthree

User has reported a bug in OnePlus two mobile, I want to debug my application for OnePlus two mobile. I tried checking in user mobile, the bug exist. Even-though i create AVD based on the same specification, i'm not able to simulate the error in AVD[i hope it is not the base native os, it might have some changes in OxygenOs]. I didn't get a chance to get connected for debugging. Please help, how to create a AVD for debugging for OnePlus2 with OxygenOS version 2.2.1, I cannot rely on mobile for debugging every time. 
Is there any sdk available for debugging OnePlus mobiles?

Pls help. This is a big blocker... Appreciate for ideas

Comment: May this help you https://paperknots.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/test-android-rom-into-sdk-emulator-before-installing-to-your-phone/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. OnePlus has not released any official emulator and the OxygenOS images available are afaik all device specific. Thus your best bet is to get your hands on the device in question and test on that. Maybe you can get lucky and find a test cloud service which runs OnePluses, but I don't know of any.

Comment: Making changes with native Android OS which is open source... Releasing the altered OS with so called premium brand #oneplus, but not supportive to the developers is really pathetic...